# How do I get Apache to serve up a web application as the root document?

Tags: apache, wildfly

I am using Apache and Wildfly.

Let's say that I own example.com and it's being served by Apache on port 80. Let's also say I have a web application, abc.war, that's being served up on port 8080 by Wildfly. What I'd like to have happen is that when a user goes to http://example.com:80, the abc webapp displays.

I've tried the following configuration in Apache and that doesn't work.

```
ProxyPass        / http://example.com:8080/abc 
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/abc
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to force your webapp to be at the root context.  In `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` you can put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

This means that your webapp is now at `http://example.com:8080/`, not at `/abc` as you're showing so your Apache config will be:

```
ProxyPass        / http://example.com:8080/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, although what I didn't mention, and probably should have, is my Wildfly is accessible from other domain names and has other webapps for those other domain names. I don't think I can have one webapp with root context and still have access to the other webapps.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to add virtual hosts to Wildfly, then followed your instructions and now it's working.